# Django - form's ChoiceField not updating immediately

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms

I have created a form in `forms.py` which uses select input based on objects from the database:

```
from controls.models import Valve

class CronjobForm(forms.Form):
    query = Valve.objects.all()
    VALVE_CHOICES = [
        (valve.pk, valve.name) for valve in query
    ]
    valves = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.Select, choices=VALVE_CHOICES)
```

At first, everything seemed to work just fine, the HTML's `<select>` with `option` got rendered.

The problem is, when I add a new `Valve` object to the database, using the Django Admin interface, it takes a while for the `ChoiceField` field to get updated - I can't see the new option on front-end immediately. I tried to reload the page, force reload, even print out the query to the terminal - the variable `query` got updated immediately, just the HTML did not.

It eventually gets updated after a while, minute or so, maybe thanks to the system checks or by repeating the `runserver` command.

So I'm wondering, what am I missing? Is there some way to force update the form? Does the form get cached and that's what causes the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the query is being evaluated when the class is defined, not when the form is instantiated.

Don't do this. Use a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), which accepts a queryset.

```
class CronjobForm(forms.Form):
    valves = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.Select, queryset=Valve.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also pass a reference of the function which will return the array for choices, as mentioned in [the choices' description of django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).

I also faced the same issue, which was resolved like this.

```
def get_valve_choices():
    return [
        (valve.pk, valve.name) for valve in Valve.objects.all()
    ]

class CronjobForm(forms.Form):
    valves = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.Select, choices=get_valve_choices)
```